# XLST to create a hyperlink http url search query. Concatenate not working

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, concatenation

I'm new to coding and this is my first question here. I have searched and tried every concatenate example I could.

I'm looking at using XSLT to create a hyperlink, in the last column of a generated table, that results/behaves in the same way as...

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/search/?q[all][]=123456" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Where 123456 is derived from `<title_id>`. I can return the title ID in the previous column, but appending it to the hyperlink as a search query is proving difficult.

I have XML (Simplified):

```
<response>

    <results>

        <result>

            <tracks>

                <track>

                    <title_id>123456</title_id>

                    <product_id>2</product_id>

                    <track_id>3</track_id>
```

I have XSL lifting what I need from the XML and creating a table ready for web...

```
 <html xsl:version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <body>
 <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
 <tr bgcolor="#fb0006" align="center">
  <td><b>#</b></td>
  <td><b>Artist</b></td>
  <td><b>Track</b></td>
  <td><b>Remix</b></td>
  <td><b>ID</b></td>
  <td><b>Link</b></td>
</tr>

 <xsl:for-each select="//response/results/result/tracks/track">

 <tr>
  <td><xsl:number value="position()" format="01" /></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="bundle_mirror_artists"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="track_title"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="track_mix_title"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="title_id"/></td>
  <td><a href="{concat('http://www.mysite.com/search/?q[all][]=', '<xsl:value-of select="title_id"/>')}" target="_blank">link </a></td>
 </tr>

 </xsl:for-each>

 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Everything works except the last `<td>`, which either fails to return anything or won't parse.

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to make the second argument a variable.

```
<xsl:variable name="title" select="title_id" />
```

And then pass `$title` as the second argument to concat.

Also I think your HTML might need to have the <a href="..."> tag closed properly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Would that go in place of `<xsl:value-of select="title_id"/>` or would I need define the variable elsewhere?

Comment: It should be able to go anywhere within the for-each loop.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much) href was fine (I think). Just added the variable and $title worked a charm.